# Putting LinearLayout to LinearLayout Array

Tags: java, android

i wanna create button 1 to 9 and i want to do that in loop. But in each 3 count, i want to create a new LinearLayout.

```
  final LinearLayout[] ll2 = new LinearLayout[10]; // create an empty array;


            for(int i=1; i<=9;i++)
            {
                Button btnNums = new Button(this);
            final LinearLayout[] ll2 = new LinearLayout[10]; // create an empty array;


            for(int i=1; i<=9;i++)
            {
                Button btnNums = new Button(this);
                btnNums.setText(i+"");
                ll.addView(btnNums);
                if(i%3==0){
                    ll2[i] = ll;
                    ll = null;

                }
            }

            layout.addView(ll2[0]);

    btnNums.setText(i+"");
            ll.addView(btnNums);
            if(i%3==0){
                ll2[i] = ll;
                ll = null;

            }
        }

        layout.addView(ll2[0]);
```

This does not work. I get no error but when o run the app, it is stopped to work. What's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a better solution would be to use a GridLayout or a Gridview

Comment: nop i have to do with linearlayout

Comment: What does stopped to work mean? It crashes or doesn't behave as expected? The code you pasted does not even compile.

Comment: yeah whats the problm

Comment: can you please post the LogCat

Answer (score 1):

I used it in my Project and it worked for me, i used it like this. Hope it helps

Declare empty array at class level:

```
LinearLayout[] imageLayoutContainers = new LinearLayout[10];
```

And then in on onCreate methord :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < imageLayoutContainers.length; i++) {
        imageLayoutContainers[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        imageLayoutContainers[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        imageLayoutContainers[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        imageLayoutContainers[i].setBackgroundResource(imagesIds[i]);
    }
```

It worked, thanks